# How do I back up my drivers so I can clean install Windows 10 onto an SSD?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd

I have a computer I bought in 2013, and I'm thinking of putting an SSD in there. My computer, Samsung NP700Z5C-S02UB, came with Windows 8, and ran 8.1 and currently runs Windows 10.

I have already downloaded Windows 10 to a USB flash drive via the Windows media creation kit. I also know my Windows license key. However, I hear that sometimes, people have installed operating systems, but have no working drivers.

How do I back up my drivers, and get them all running on the SSD I plan to install?

Comment: You don't need to know your Windows 10 license key in order to install it on the SSD.  When prompted for the key, indicate you don't have a key, the key you "have" I will almost guarantee is the generic Windows 10 key.  Furthermore if you want the device drivers, go the OEM website, and download them.  Backing up drivers isn't worth the time.  Do not trust "driver downloaders" either, download drivers manually, yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Backing up drivers Using DISM**

Source: [DISM Exports Drivers: Here's How - Windows Enterprise Desktop](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/windows-enterprise-desktop/dism-exports-drivers-heres-how/)

Use this command-line syntax:

```
dism /online /export-driver /destination:D:\DriversW10
```

Run that command from Administrator Command Prompt.

**Backing up drivers Using PowerShell**

Start PowerShell as administrator, and execute this command-line/syntax:

```
Export-WindowsDriver -Online -Destination D:\DriversW10
```

Reference: PowerShell's [Export-WindowsDriver cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614084.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[image]

**Restoring a driver from backup**

After clean installing Windows, open Device Manager and right-click the device for which you want to install the driver, and click `Update Driver Software`. Select `Browse my computer for driver software`. Specify the folder that contains your driver backups and complete the process.

Comment: You might want to add specific information on how to import the drivers once you have exported them.

Comment: Already done. Please see last part of the answer.