# Moving Windows 10 System Drivers to Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2022 installation and I want to connect a Logitech F710 Controller, turns out the device uses Window's included default xusb22 drivers for this but this driver and the whole Xbox 360 Peripherals driver category does not exist in Server 2022, is there a way to move these drivers from a Windows 10 installation to the Server 2022 installation?

Comment: Why would you want to attach a consumer-level gaming device to an enterprise-level server machine? They're not designed for this sort of hardware, which is why the driver support isn't there.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://superuser.com/questions/1110465/how-do-i-back-up-my-drivers-so-i-can-clean-install-windows-10-onto-an-ssd/1110470#1110470 . How to export drivers from W10.

Comment: @spikey_richie I've asked your question to myself many times, more than you can imagine and came to the conclusion that it's a matter of "can I" rather than "should I" and for now it seems likely that I can't.

Comment: Windows stores drivers within `%WinDir%\INF`, however IIRC you'll also need to locate the applicable `.cab`, and possiblly `.h`, file(s) for the driver

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmBus/issues/85#issuecomment-800720933), I installed [this driver](http://web.archive.org/web/20200425215425/http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/4/69446ACF-E625-4CCF-8F56-58B589934CD3/Xbox360_64Eng.exe) and it worked for me in Windows Server 2019 (even though the driver seems to be for Windows 7).

No need to run the .exe, just open the file with WinRAR or similar, extract its contents, go to Device Manager, right click on the device (under Other devices), Update driver... but if you're messing with Windows Server I suppose you already know this.

Note: in case the file goes missing in the future, its name is *Xbox360_64Eng.exe*, its SHA256 is 0e72ed6d89d9b89690fde8122f46fa851740ef18e850d98d45e56f85a6682994 and it installs version 2.1.0.1349 of the driver.

Edit: the same driver works for Windows Server 2022 too.